# What is promo graphic on play store?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am uploading my app on play store.It is asking me for promotional graphic.I have read google support it says

> The promo graphic is used for promotions on older versions of the
>   Android OS (earlier than 4.0). This image is not required to submit an
>   update for your Store Listing.

What type of image it should be can i use feature graphic image for this?